# Error at creating a List View template in MVC, stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to create a listview template in ASP.NET MVC and fill it through a stored procedure model class from the database, I am using EF, however when I try to create the view the following error is displayed:

> Unable to retrieve metadata for JobPortalCandidates.SP_CND_Positions_Result

The name of the stored procedure is `SP_CND_Positions`.

View Template Wizard in VS:

```
View Name: Index
Template: List
Model Class: SP_CND_Positions_Result (JobPortalCandidatesMVC)
```

This is my controller

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CandidateEntities Positions = new CandidateEntities();
    return View(Positions.SP_CND_Positions());
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this thread https://forums.asp.net/t/2051386.aspx?Error+when+adding+View+Unable+to+retrieve+metadata+for+efEntity+Could+not+find+the+CLR+type+for+Model+

Comment: **Side note**: if this is in SQL Server - you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: The result is basically the same. I changed the name of the SP and it still is displaying the same error.